# Splitting a string at a particular character meeting a criteria

Tags: string, scala, split

I got a Vector written to a text file..like
Vector((a1,b1,c1),(a2,b2,c2),........)
This a long string which I can read from text file and store in a String variable say v. I want to split the string 'v' not at all commas but at the commas separating the Tuples only ie., after the closing parenthesis of each tuple into an array.
How to do that in Scala? ( Given that the middle element of each tuple is not again a tuple and doesn't contain any parentheses at start and end.)

Comment: `"Vector((a1,b1,c1),(a2,b2,c2),........) ".split("),(")` ?

Comment: I checked. It doesn't work. I want to split only at commas after closing parenthesis of each tuple..I should retain the closing parenthesis and opening  parenthesis in tact for each tuple.

Comment: Only at commas between parenthesis splitting required. The parentheses should be retained in the tuplelike strings of the resulting array.

Comment: Try using `split("(?<=\\G\\S+,\\S+,\\S+),")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to write your own **parser**. Here is an example:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

class Parser extends RegexParsers {

  def id = "[a-z0-9]+".r

  def value: Parser[Any] = id | tuple

  def tuple = "(" ~ rep1sep(value, ",") ~ ")" ^^ {
    case _ ~ List(v1, v2, v3) ~ _ => (v1, v2, v3)
  }

  def tuples = rep1sep(tuple, ",")

  def vector = "Vector(" ~ tuples ~ ")" ^^ {
    case _ ~ tuples ~ _ => tuples
  }
}

val string = "Vector((a1,(aa1, (aaa1, bbb1, ccc1), cc1),c1),(a2,b2,c2),(a3,b3,c3))"
val parser = new Parser
val result = parser.parseAll(parser.vector, string)
val res = result.get
```

produces:

```
res: List[(Any, Any, Any)] = List((a1,(aa1,(aaa1,bbb1,ccc1),cc1),c1), (a2,b2,c2), (a3,b3,c3))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested this fully but this should work:

```
v.split(",?(?=\\([\\w,]*\\))")
```

It might get some blank entries too, and the `Vector(` and `)` will still be there, and if this happens you'd need to do something like:

```
val v = """Vector((a1,b1,c1),(a2,b2,c2),(a3,b3,c3))"""

v.replaceAll("Vector\\((.*)\\)", "$1")
  .split(",?(?=\\([\\w,]*\\))")
  .filter(_.trim != "")
```

It's a little messy and can probably be cleaned up but it should work. In terms of how the regex works:

- `,?` - optional comma (optional denoted by `?`)
- `(?= .... )` - positive lookahead
- `\\( .... \\)` - escaped brackets (brackets are regex special characters)
- `[\\w,]*` - any word character or comma, any number of times

Note: This solution is if you want to use `split`. I'd recommend using the Scala Regex library though as it will be a little neater (though I'm not sure of the performance implications of each method).

Also note: In normal Regex, you only need one backslash to escape a character but Scala requires two.

Answer (score 0):

Use **regex** which detects the tupples (*assuming there are no brackets within tupples*) and stay away from array, but use something like list:

```
val regex = "\\([^\\(\\)]+?\\)".r
val string = "Vector((a1,b1,c1),(a2,b2,c2),(a3,b3,c3))"
val iterator = regex.findAllIn(string)
iterator.toList.foreach(println)
```

produces:

```
(a1,b1,c1)
(a2,b2,c2)
(a3,b3,c3)
```

[see and play here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bUxVLgrTTOucLgtqPpr7jA)

Comment: Tuple may contain another tuple as one of it's component. Say c1 is another tuple within the tuple (a1,b1,c1). That is possible. So brackets are inevetable in some cases.

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM if a tupple can be part of another tupple, how do you envisage "flattening" of the de-facto tree of tupples (rather than a list of tupples)?   Are you allowing for some reference, i.e `(a1,b1,$c1) where $c1=(a15,b15,c15)`?

Comment: Ok..I realise this can be a bit involved thing. Because again inside atuple there can occur &quot;),(&quot;  issue. Let&#39;s say I want to separate the outermost Tuple like Strings only to be populated into the splitted array.

Comment: Then dyrkin's answer is the one.